# Deutsche Börse sample Level 2 data, how to view in Windows?

Tags: data

DB has some sample Level 2 market data:

http://deutsche-boerse.com/mda/dispatch/en/listcontent/gdb_navigation/mda/200_market_data/650_historical_market_data/35_enbs_hist_data_xetra/EnBS_historical_data_Xetra.htm

In particular:

http://deutsche-boerse.com/mda/dispatch/en/listcontent/gdb_content_pool/imported_files/public_files/10_downloads/50_informations_services/47_enbs/EnBS_XTR13F1_20121126-0900-0905.dmp.gz

However, once I downloaded the file and un-zipped it in windows using Winrar I was presented with a .dmp file and no program could interpret it.

**How can I view this data on Windows?**

Answer (score 2):

It's an ordinary FIX/FAST stream for which you'd need a FIX/FAST decoder.

We're not using Windows, so don't take my word for it, but google thinks [the FAST Antenna Codec for Windows](http://www.b2bits.com/performance_lab/fast_antenna_codec/fast_codec_windows.html) could work.